# How can I write emoji characters to a textarea

Tags: javascript, unicode, reactjs, textarea, emoji

I'm trying to setup an emoji picker control for a form that will post to various social media networks. I am trying to implement `emojione-picker` (https://github.com/tommoor/emojione-picker) which provides a `data` object that looks like this when you click on an emoji icon:

```
{
    "unicode":"1f600",
    "unicode_alternates":"",
    "name":"grinning face",
    "shortname":":grinning:",
    ...
}
```

I don't want to use the `shortname` property, but rather the `unicode` value for the actual emoji. I want to insert the unicode value at the current cursor position of a `<textarea>` on the page. I'm using the form value to post to Twitter which expect the actual emoji character (not :smile: or \u1f600 )

After reading this article (http://crocodillon.com/blog/parsing-emoji-unicode-in-javascript), I found that I can use a findSerrogatePair method to convert the unicode value into the escape sequence (?) Like this:

```
function findSurrogatePair(point) {
  // assumes point > 0xffff
  var offset = point - 0x10000,
      lead = 0xd800 + (offset >> 10),
      trail = 0xdc00 + (offset & 0x3ff); 
  return [lead.toString(16), trail.toString(16)];
}
```

Then I tried this:
`foo = findSurrogatePair('0x1f600') => ["d83d", "de00"]`

Using these values, I can see the actual smiley face character log to the console:

`console.log("\ud83d\ude00")` 
=> (actual smily emoji)

But if I try to read the values from `foo` and add the \u, I see the character code:

`console.log("\\u" + foo[0] + "\\u" + foo[1])` 
=> "\ud83d\ude00"

If I just use a single backslash:

`console.log("\u" + foo[0] + "\u" + foo[1])`

I get this error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL(…)`

Comment: 0x1f600 is actually a number, not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use String.fromCharCode:

```
findSurrogatePair(0x1f600)
.map((el) => parseInt(el, 16))
.map((el) => String.fromCharCode(el))
.join('')
```

But then you're converting number to string in `findSurrogatePair` and the n back to number here with `parseInt`..

Comment: Thanks! That works. Do you have a better suggestion to achieve the same result? As it stands now, I have to add the `0x` to the value passed from `data` and using this complicated method to convert to string then back to int.

Answer (score 0):

More concise way:

```
function findSurrogatePair(point) {
  var offset = point - 0x10000,
      lead = 0xd800 + (offset >> 10),
      trail = 0xdc00 + (offset & 0x3ff); 
  return String.fromCharCode(lead) + String.fromCharCode(trail);
}
```

credit to: jnes